# SQL: Why does Max() from multiple tables return NULL for everything if one table is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null, max

I have a MySQL 5.1.44 Database that I'm using with PHP 5.3.1.

```
SELECT MAX(t1.tstamp) AS tstamp1, MAX(t2.tstamp) AS tstamp2 FROM table1 t1, table2 t2;
```

This **works perfectly well if both tables contain content**, but it **returns NULL for both (!) even if only one of the tables is empty**. Why does it not simply return the correct value for table1 and null for table2?

Comment: Because you are cross joining the 2 tables. The (intermediate) result table has (`0 x N =`) `0` rows.

Comment: Better write separate query for each tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two queries - cross join with an empty table will result zero rows

Something like this should do the work

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(tstamp) FROM table1) AS tstamp1,
    (SELECT MAX(tstamp) FROM table2) AS tstamp2;
```

Comment: works great, thanks! btw: can't there be more than one correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are cross joining the 2 tables. The (intermediate) result table has (`0 x N =`) `0` rows.

Your query is:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(t1.tstamp) AS tstamp1, 
    MAX(t2.tstamp) AS tstamp2 
FROM 
    table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2 ;
```

You could work around the problem by running 2 subqueries and then `UNION` them, which would return either 0, 1 or 2 rows:

```
SELECT 
    'table1' AS tablename, MAX(tstamp) AS tstamp
FROM 
    table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    'table2' AS tablename, MAX(tstamp) AS tstamp
FROM 
    table2 ;
```

or if you want strictly 1 row and `NULL` result when a table has no rows, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(t1.tstamp) AS tstamp1, 
    MAX(t2.tstamp) AS tstamp2 
FROM 
    (SELECT 1) AS dummy
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON TRUE 
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON TRUE ;
```

or this:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT MAX(tstamp) FROM table1)  AS tstamp1, 
    (SELECT MAX(tstamp) FROM table2)  AS tstamp2
FROM 
    dual ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you observe is likely due to one of the tables being empty. (If one of the tables is empty, then the JOIN operation won't return any rows.)

Here's a query which is one way to workaround the issue:

```
SELECT d1.tstamp1, d2.tstamp2
  FROM ( SELECT MAX(t1.tstamp) AS tstamp1 FROM t1 ) d1
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t2.tstamp) AS tstamp2 FROM t2 ) d2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `left join` and find the MAX of table values
2. Use separate query

If there is no relation between the tables use separate query and find the max values